truth value of a conditional involving propositional functions as antecedent and consequent
Assume we have three propositional functions based on the real-valued variable x:
A(x) :=  x > 0
B(x) :=  x > -2
C(x) :=  x > 3
And I construct the conditional statements S1, S2 from the predicates A, B, C as:
S1(x) :=  A ---> B
S2(x) :=  A ---> C
We know that the truth values of A, B, C depend on the particular value of x being used. Thus, for example, when x = 7, all of A, B, C are true, while when x=-1, A is false, B is true and C is false; and if x = -5 all are false.
Now my question is on the interpretation of the truth value of these conditionals?
It can be seen that S1(x) is true for all x :
when  0 < x     : A is true, B is true thus  A ---> B is true,
when -2 < x < 0 : A is false, B is true thus A ---> B is true,
when  x < -2    : A is false, B is true thus A ---> B is true,
Therefore, we can conclude that S1(x) is true for all values of x, hence I consider the implication S1(x) as a true statement.
However, for S2(x), it can be seen that its truth depends on x:
when  3 < x     : A is true,  C is true thus  A ---> C is true,
when 0 < x < 3  : A is true,  C is false thus A ---> C is false,
when  x < 0     : A is false, C is false thus A ---> C is true,
Now, how do we interpret S2(x) in genral ?
1-) Should I call it false? Because it's not true for all x?
2-) Should I cal it true?? Because it's not false for all x?
3-) should I leave it as a propositional-conditional, and not assign an absolute truth value to it? Then how do I use it in a theorem proof ?
Which way is to go ?

@TankutBeygu they are not sufficiently similar. My question is not a general discussion, but a very specific example. And I cannot see how the linked question helps. But If honestly you think that it provides an asnwer to my question (which I cannot see honestly) can you please comment here the  "anwser" to my question (at the bottom), inferred possibly from that linked question?
